# Parse Setup at Appdelage

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server

Hi I'm trying to set Parse. Anyone let me know is this steps right?

And where is put this code?

PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(nil)

Anyone check my init step?

I think It will helps other new Parse Users.

Thanks

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Hidden statusbar
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
        Parse.setLogLevel(PFLogLevel.info);

        //Initialize Pare
        let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {
            (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
            //back4app
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "xxxxxxxxx";
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "xxxxxxxxx";
            //Parse LiveQuery Server
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://xxxxxxxxx/";



        });


        Parse.initialize(with: config);


        //Initialize Facebook
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)

 PFTwitterUtils.initializeWithConsumerKey("xxxxxx", consumerSecret: "xxxxxx")


        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
        buildUserInterface()

        // color of window
        window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        //Set Fabric
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

        //register ParseSubclass
        configureParse()

        let userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `appdelegate` is fine!  Unfortunately parse-server doesn't support `PFAnalytics` at this time. So that will not work.

You would have to make use of other tools such as Google , fabric's etc.

I noticed you tagged swift to your question. Your setup is objective C but with swift its different.

**Swift 3**

```
// Init Parse
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "XXX"
    $0.clientKey = "XXX"
    $0.server = "XXX"
    $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true

}
Parse.initialize(with: configuration)

PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions);
        PFConfig.getInBackground{(config: PFConfig?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                //print(config?["OfflineMode"])
            }
        }
```

You will also need to add `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` outside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Also don't forget to add the frameworks for the selective social platforms or  analytics you use. In that instance i would suggest using CocoaPods as a dependency manager.

Works with Swift & Objective C.

Comment: awesome Thank you so much It helps me a lot :)